# which python module is use to find directory permission in remote server SSH

Tags: python, linux, ssh, remote-server

as per my knowledge os.access is use to check directory existence in local area. and it read permission can be check with os.r_ok but if same directory is present in remote location then how we can check its read permission?

Comment: are you trying to know the file permissions or is it a situation where you need to find the permissions inside your app of ours ?

Comment: i have to to check if directory is exist in remote server SSH then user is having read and write permission or not in that directory?

Comment: if you are trying in a pythonic way then please check the file path . Add your sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Try [paramiko](http://www.paramiko.org/installing.html)

```
pip install paramiko
```

This is just a sample, change values.

```
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()

ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

host = '111.111.1.1'
user = 'username'
pass = 'password'

ssh.connect(host, username=user, password=pass, allow_agent = False)

my_command = 'ls -la /path/to/folder/file'
i, o, e = ssh.exec_command(my_command)

print(o.readlines())
```

To find the permissions over ssh the command is

```
ls -la /path/to/folder/file
```

Do a looping function to find out the permissions from the result for the command.

Here the permissions will look similar to this `-rw-r--r--`.

You may need to look into Linux file permissions further for understanding the notations.